# Display a Toast message if a checkbox is TRUE

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience, notification, toast

I've been trying to figure out if it is possible to show a toast message on a contact record if a checkbox is true (or if a text field is not blank). I just want the toast message to show once the page is opened if the checkbox is TRUE. Does anyone know if this is possible?

```
<aura:component access="global" 

<lightning:notificationsLibrary aura:id="notifLib"/>

<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.handleShowToast}"/>       

</aura:component>
```

---

```
({
    handleShowToast : function(component, event, helper){

        var chk = component.find("v.Marketing_Opportunity_Alert__c").get("v.value");

        if(chk){         

        component.find('notifLib').showToast({

            "title" : "Alert",

            "message" : "THIS CONTACT IS ON A MARKETING OPPORTUNITY",

            "variant" : "Success"

        });

    }

    }

})
```

Comment: Generically speaking, yes, it's possible. Can you be more specific?

Comment: I created a component and that JS controller and all I want is to check if my checkbox (Marketing_Opportunity_Alert__c) on the contact object is true, If true return he toast message else do nothing. I hope the question makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just get arbitrary data the way you're thinking of. You need to use Lightning Data Service, like this:

```
<aura:attribute name="record" type="Map" default="{}" />
<force:recordData 
    recordId="{!v.recordId}" 
    layoutType="FULL" 
    targetFields="{!v.record}" 
    recordUpdated="{!c.optionalShowToast}" />
```

---

```
({
    optionalShowToast: function(component, event, helper){
        var chk = component.get("v.record.Marketing_Opportunity_Alert__c");
        if(chk){         
        component.find('notifLib').showToast({
            title: "Alert",
            message: "THIS CONTACT IS ON A MARKETING OPPORTUNITY",
            variant: "info"
        });
    }
    }
})
```

I recommend "info" since this is informational. Also, be careful: `Success` is not the same as `success`; the variant is lowercased.

Comment: hmm maybe I'm doing something wrong but the toast message isn't showing. I just want the message to show when the page is loaded and that checkbox is true.

Comment: @R.Marin Might need to do some debugging. This should work. Do you have implements="force:hasRecordId" in the component markup?

Comment: I do <aura: component implements="force:hasRecordId"/> , okay let me debug and see what I find.

Comment: You were right it does work! Thank you very much!

Comment: @R.Marin Great, glad I could help!